# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.aol.Application" on path: DexPathList error flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to run a project but I found an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.aol.Application" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.aol-1JWhf7hk26dkh1US0WG4tg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.aol-1JWhf7hk26dkh1US0WG4tg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.example.aol-1JWhf7hk26dkh1US0WG4tg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
```

So does any one have any idea about the below error:

[image: error]

and this is the related `manifest`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.aol" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <application
        android:name=".Application" 
        tools:replace="android:label"
        android:label="aol"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
           
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.braintreepayments.api.BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="${applicationId}.braintree" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <!-- TODO: Replace with your real AdMob app ID -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value= "@string/android__admob_ads_id_key" />
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

this is the full error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi 5 in debug mode...
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...                38.0s
E/AndroidRuntime(14356): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(14356): Process: com.example.aol, PID: 14356
E/AndroidRuntime(14356): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.aol.Application: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.aol.Application" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.aol-1JWhf7hk26dkh1US0WG4tg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.aol-1JWhf7hk26dkh1US0WG4tg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.example.aol-1JWhf7hk26dkh1US0WG4tg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(14356):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:993)
E/AndroidRuntime(14356):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5801)
E/AndroidRuntime(14356):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(14356):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1685)
E/AndroidRuntime(14356):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(14356):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
/AndroidRuntime(14356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
E/AndroidRuntime(14356):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(14356):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
E/AndroidRuntime(14356):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
E/AndroidRuntime(14356): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.aol.Application" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.aol-1JWhf7hk26dkh1US0WG4tg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.aol-1JWhf7hk26dkh1US0WG4tg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.example.aol-1JWhf7hk26dkh1US0WG4tg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(14356):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime(14356):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(14356):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(14356):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1088)
E/AndroidRuntime(14356):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:987)
E/AndroidRuntime(14356):    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Please post error messages directly into the question, not as images.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore thanks for your comment I have updated my question :D

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same error. In my case, the `Application.java` file was under `main/java/`.  I solved it by creating another folder under the java folder and I put inside it the Application file, so the path becomes as following; `main/java/your_folder_name/Application.java`. Don't forget to update the new path in the `AndroidManifest` file, so it becomes something like:

```
.
.
.
<application
    <!--Here-->
    android:name=".your_folder_name.Application" 
    tools:replace="android:label"
    android:label="aol"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

Another reason, it could also be due to the fact that your `Application.java` is in a different package than the one you specified at the `AndroidManifest`.

Answer (score 2):

I see that for newer created Flutter apps `android:name` in `application` tag from `AndroidManifest.xml` is no longer present. If you don't have anything custom in your Activity.kt, you can just delete that XML attribute.

[Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#nm) state that it's optional.

Answer (score 0):

Remove android:name="com.yourpackage.xxxxx"

```
<application
        android:name="com.yourpackage.xxxxx"
        android:label="routingo"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
```